# Python - Can't open file: 'data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml' in read mode

Tags: python, opencv, path

I'm following along this tutorial for depth estimation: https://learnopencv.com/depth-perception-using-stereo-camera-python-c/

Using python3 in a virtual env on my MacBook Pro. I'm running this block of code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

# Check for left and right camera IDs
# These values can change depending on the system
CamL_id = 2 # Camera ID for left camera
CamR_id = 1 # Camera ID for right camera

CamL= cv2.VideoCapture(CamL_id)
CamR= cv2.VideoCapture(CamR_id)

# Reading the mapping values for stereo image rectification
cv_file = cv2.FileStorage("data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
Left_Stereo_Map_x = cv_file.getNode("Left_Stereo_Map_x").mat()
Left_Stereo_Map_y = cv_file.getNode("Left_Stereo_Map_y").mat()
Right_Stereo_Map_x = cv_file.getNode("Right_Stereo_Map_x").mat()
Right_Stereo_Map_y = cv_file.getNode("Right_Stereo_Map_y").mat()
cv_file.release()
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
[ERROR:0@1.008] global /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp (505) open Can't open file: 'data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml' in read mode
```

I've tried using different methods like cv2.FileStorage.open(filename,flags) but I get similar errors. I've also tried to open in write mode and got a similar error. Any help would be great!

Comment: `assert os.path.exists("data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml"), os.getcwd()`

Comment: if that assertion passes, the file exists... so failure to load probably indicates a corrupted file. if that assertion fails, you'll get a traceback saying so. that means the file doesn't exist and you should think about what path you are getting from `getcwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too late but I stumbled upon the same issue and found the .xml file in a github page associated with the tutorial.

https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/Depth-Perception-Using-Stereo-Camera/data/stereo_rectify_maps.xml